# How to trigger another click event if already one exist

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

I am new with the jQuery. I am trying to fire another click event on element which already have click event bind.

I tried this by using unbind event but did not get success.
**I tried :**

```
$('li.main-menu').unbind('click').bind( "click", function() {
  alert( "click sub menu" );
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<li class="main-menu"><a href="/" class="active"><span class="menu-item-inner-wrap">Main Menu</span></a>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="sub-menu"><a href="test.php"><span class="menu-item-inner-wrap">ABC</span></a></li>
    <li class="sub-menu"><a href="">XYZ</span></a></li>
   <li class="sub-menu"><a href="">PQR</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('li.main-menu', nav).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        return false;   
});
```

Here main-menu has click event so once I click on sub-menu same event is triggering because sub-menu is child of main menu.

I am trying to fire another click event on sub-menu. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `event.stopPropagation()` and read [this](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: What about a click function that targets `.main-menu` and a second that targets `.sub-nav` to avoid `event.stopPropagation()`?